# Show state of backend service availability in the frontend in (near) realtime

Tags: c#, rest, api, xamarin

my frontend uses .NET Core 3 and Xamarin. I also have an API for the backend including an API call that returns "Healthy" if the backend services are available. I want to show that in the front end via a simple image, that turns green if "Healthy" and red if not.

What would be the best approach here? Run the API call every x seconds in a background thread? Or is there anything 'smoother'?

Comment: Call the api every x seconds or create a long connection between your app and server side, every time status changes, push a state change notification to your app. You should also consider those situations like no-network, app in background and etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and the best way, in my opinion, would be calling the API repeatedly

(every few minutes and before calling any other backend service) asking for the "Healthy" status.